# Recursively get children in hierarchy with identifier for haschildren

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is how do I tag an identifier in returned row that will tell me whether or not returned row.id has more children

```
Sample Data
id  parenId Name parentName 
9   8        nine   eight
8   7        eight  seven
6   8        six    eight
5   8        five   eight
4   8        four   eight
3   8        three  eight
2   1        two    one
1   1        one    one
12  7        tweleve  seven
11  12      eleven  twelve
```

**if I pass parentId of 7 in this query below it returns me**

```
8   7 eight
6   8   six
5   8   five
4   8 four
3   8 three
12  7   tweleve
11  12  eleven
```

**But what I want is for id that has more children be flagged for example 8 and 12 have more children**

```
8   7 eight   haschidlren
6   8   six
5   8   five
4   8 four
3   8 three
12  7   tweleve   haschidlren
11  12  eleven

WITH name_tree
     AS (SELECT Id,
                Parentid,
                Name,
                ParentName
         FROM   TableWithHiearchy
         WHERE  Parentid = 7
         -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
         UNION ALL
         SELECT c.Id,
                c.Parentid,
                c.Name,
                ParentName
         FROM   TableWithHiearchy c
                JOIN name_tree p
                  ON p.Id = c.ParentId -- this is the recursion
                     AND c.Id <> c.Parentid

                     )
SELECT distinct Id, parenId, Name 

FROM   name_tree
```

Comment: You could just add a column to the CTE like `hasChildren = case when exists (select 1 from tablewithhierarchy where parentid = c.id then 1 else 0 end)` then give `TableWithHiearchy` in the first part of the recursive CTE the alias `c`

Comment: not sure i follow your last part "then give TableWithHiearchy in the first part of the recursive CTE the alias c"

Comment: Like `WITH name_tree AS (SELECT Id, Parentid, Name, ParentName, hasChildren = case when exists (select 1 from tablewithhierarchy where parentid = c.id) then 1 else 0 end FROM   TableWithHiearchy AS c WHERE  Parentid = 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add a column to the query for `case when exists (id is parent) then true else false end`

rextester link: http://rextester.com/RAU96705

```
create table TableWithHiearchy (
    id int
  , parentid int
  , name varchar(32)
  , parentname varchar(32)
)
insert into TableWithHiearchy values 
(9,8,'nine','eight')
,(8,7,'eight','seven')
,(6,8,'six','eight')
,(5,8,'five','eight')
,(4,8,'four','eight')
,(3,8,'three','eight')
,(2,1,'two','one')
,(1,1,'one','one')
,(12,7,'tweleve','seven')
,(11,12,'eleven','twelve');

with name_tree as (
  select 
        Id
      , Parentid
      , Name
      , ParentName
      , [Path]=convert(varchar(64), 
                isnull(convert(varchar(10),ParentId) + '.','') 
                + convert(varchar(10),Id)
                 )
    from   TableWithHiearchy
    where  ParentId = 7
    -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
    union all
    select 
          c.Id
        , c.Parentid
        , c.Name
        , c.ParentName --=p.Name
        , Path=convert(varchar(64),p.Path + '.' + convert(varchar(10),c.Id))
      from   TableWithHiearchy c
        join name_tree p
          on p.Id = c.ParentId -- this is the recursion
            and c.Id <> c.Parentid
)
select distinct Id, parentId, Name, Path
  , HasChildren= case 
      when exists (
          select 1 
            from name_tree i
            where i.parentid=o.id
            ) 
      then 'HasChildren'
      else '' 
      end
from   name_tree o
```

results in

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Id | parentId |  Name   |  Path   | HasChildren |
+----+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
|  3 |        8 | three   | 7.8.3   |             |
|  4 |        8 | four    | 7.8.4   |             |
|  5 |        8 | five    | 7.8.5   |             |
|  6 |        8 | six     | 7.8.6   |             |
|  8 |        7 | eight   | 7.8     | HasChildren |
|  9 |        8 | nine    | 7.8.9   |             |
| 11 |       12 | eleven  | 7.12.11 |             |
| 12 |        7 | tweleve | 7.12    | HasChildren |
+----+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

I added the path just so I could see straight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.

In cte0, we normalize you table (remember to replace @YourTable with your actual table name.

In cteP, we build your hierarchy.

When **@Top** is set to **NULL**, you'll get the entire hierarchy, otherwise specify the desired top ID.

Could easily be a TVF or stored procedure where you pass the @Top as a parameter

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,parentId int,Name varchar(25),parentName varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(9,   8, 'nine'   ,'eight'),
(8,   7, 'eight'  ,'seven'),
(6,   8, 'six'    ,'eight'),
(5,   8, 'five'   ,'eight'),
(4,   8, 'four'   ,'eight'),
(3,   8, 'three'  ,'eight'),
(2,   1, 'two'    ,'one'),
(1,   1, 'one'    ,'one'),
(12,  7, 'tweleve','seven'),
(11,  12,'eleven' ,'twelve')

Declare @Top  int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 8 or 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cte0 as (
      Select Distinct ID,ParentID,Name From @YourTable
      Union All 
      Select Distinct ID=parentID,ParentID=NULL,Name=parentName From @YourTable where ParentID not in (Select Distinct ID From @YourTable) ),
      cteP as (
      Select Distinct
             Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by ID) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,parentId
            ,Name
            ,Lvl=1
      From   cte0 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(parentId,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.ID)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.parentId
            ,r.Name
            ,p.Lvl+1
      From   cte0 r
      Join   cteP p on r.parentId = p.ID and r.id<>r.parentId)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP )
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.parentId
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title       = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
      ,HasChildren = case when A.R1<>B.R2 then 'haschildren' else '' end
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID 
 Order By A.R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Now, if you set **@Top** to **8**, you'll get

[image]